# VB.Net Only getting 1 image with TCP

Tags: vb.net, image, networking, tcp, stream

I have recently decided to create an app to view other computers desktops, Os far i can see the desktop but it seems to only send 1 image :? Im using a TCP client and some threading on the client side(The one that views the desktop). When the server sends an image it seems to lock up afterwards and becomes unrepsonsive
**Client Recevie Code:**

```
    Private Sub check()
    If sock.Connected = True Then
        sock.SendTimeout = 5000
        Try
            Application.DoEvents()
            Dim nstream As NetworkStream
            Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter
            nstream = sock.GetStream
            PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
            PictureBox1.Image = bf.Deserialize(nstream)
            If nstream.DataAvailable = True Then
                MsgBox(nstream)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            check()
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

And then this is the code for sending it
**Sending code:**

```
    Public Function Desktop() As Image
    Dim bounds As Rectangle = Nothing
    Dim screenshot As System.Drawing.Bitmap = Nothing
    Dim graph As Graphics = Nothing
    bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
    screenshot = New Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    graph = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot)
    graph.CopyFromScreen(bounds.X, bounds.Y, 0, 0, bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)
    Return screenshot
End Function

Private Sub SendDesk()
    If sock.Connected = True Then
        Try
            Dim nstream As NetworkStream
            Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter
            nstream = sock.GetStream
            bf.Serialize(nstream, Desktop())
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

I have been coding in Vb.net for awhile (Basic stuff, some HTTP stuff) but im new to TCP and Network streams, Any help is greatly apreciated, Thanks!

Comment: No idea , so my first suggestion would be to stop swallowing the exceptions, and hope for a clue. A tip, even if you want your code to continue regardless of any exception, always log it, and it's stack trace. And you might want to add some indication that soc.connected is false. May be it died or was disposed after one successful call?

Comment: Thanks for your reply i tried this by first removing the try's and after that did't throw any errors i put in something to display errors and still nothing :( And then i put and else in when it sends the image to see if it was disconnected from the socket and the app still says it is connected :/ This is really bugging me :( anymore help is ofc apreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to repeat the image sending process...

```
While sock.Connected = True
        Try
            Dim nstream As NetworkStream
            Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter
            nstream = sock.GetStream
            bf.Serialize(nstream, Desktop())
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End While
```